# append data to an existing Json file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, fs, in-memory, storing-data

i'm trying to add new data in an existing json file  named `db.json` which i use to store data locally aka inMemory.So i tried many ways to achieve that but still not working as expected Since the add operation replaced the existing data.
For example i want something like this :

```
{
  "users": [,
    {
      "email": "johnDoe@gmail.com",
      "password": "blabala",
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "address": "4 rue gay lussac",
      "city": "Paris",

    },
    {
      "email": "new email",
      "password": "new password",
      "firstname": "new firstname",
      "lastname": "new lastname",
      "address": "new address",
      "city": "new city",
    }
  ],
}
```

i'm currently working in nodejs using the `writeFileSync`() method from `fs` library.
My index.js looks like this :

```
server.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const {firstname, lastname, email, password,address, city} = req.body
    if(firstname && lastname && email && password && address && city) {
        try {
            fs.readFile("db.json")
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "db.json"),JSON.stringify(req.body), {encoding: "utf-8"})
            res.status(201).send({
                message: "User created!"
           })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({
                code: error.code,
                message: error.message
            })
        }
    }else{
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Something wrong"
        })
    }
})
```

Need some suggestions please. Thks!!

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same thing as you long time ago, you have to extract the content of the file as a JSON Object, modify it and then write it stringifyied in your file.

I still have a snippet of what I've done in the past:

```
const getUsers = () => {
    let users = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../workspace/.users.json'));
    return JSON.parse(users);
};

const setUsers = (users) => {
    let newUsersObject = JSON.stringify(users, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../workspace/.users.json'), newUsersObject);
};
```

So with this two functions you can do things like:

```
//retrieve users
let userObject = getUsers();

//edit the first user (example)
userObject[0].firstname = "John";
userObject[1].lastname = "Doe";

//save the modified object
setUsers(userObject);
```

Comment: Look good but not enough to achieve the operation that i want.  Thus, i found from myself the solution which completely solved my problem.  instead of do `userObject[0].firstname = "some value"`  which in my sens does override the precedente value, i do `userObject.users.push({myObjectToAdd})`